# No JSON response in jQuery form plugin in IE9

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I use http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm to my forms.
I set up an form to upload images to the server by Ajax. Everything works fine without IE9 :).
I can't get the JSON response from the server, although on the other browsers it works correctly.
I tried to put some alert() within the success function, but it looks the success function isn't event loaded.

My JS code:

```
$(function() {

    $('#upload-image').ajaxForm({
        dataType:  'json',
        success: processJson
    });

    function processJson(data) {
        var i = 0;
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $('<li id="image_' + key + '"><input type="checkbox" name="delete_image[' + key + ']" /><img src="' + val + '" alt=""/></li>').hide().appendTo('#images').delay(i).fadeIn('slow');
            i += 1000;
        });
    }

});
```

and code to generate JSON response in PHP:

```
    $output = array();

    foreach ($files['Filedata'] as $file)
    {
        $file_arr = $this->_save_image($file);

        $image = ORM::factory('image');

        $image->filename = $file_arr['filename'];
        $image->gallery_id = $gallery_id;
        $image->save();

        $output[$image->id] = Route::get('uploads')->uri(array('dir' => 'images/120x120', 'file' => $image->filename));

    }
    $this->request->headers('Content-type','application/json; charset='.Kohana::$charset);
    $this->response->body(json_encode($output));
```

I found some posts about similar issues (to remove html tags from the response), but it doesn't help me.
What is wrong?

EDIT:
The IE debug mode told me that the access has been denied on the line with "form.submit();" within the jQuery form plugin library.
It seems to be some kind of security denial related with running javascript on localhost.

Comment: try to comment out your $this->request->headers line and check. because if you are passing dataType:json, then you doesn't need to set json header from your php

Comment: Comment this line doesn't help. My action is set within the form tag directly.

Comment: Maybe it's caused that I use different that 80 port for apache? I have two servers, one IIS on the 80 port and apache on the 81 port. However, the URls looks correctly in every moment my application goes.

Comment: what the response of request http? 200 OK, 302 ,500 or something?

Answer (score 3):

This can be an error caused by IE9 by not recognising the Character Set. I had to face a similar problem.

I this this should help

```
$.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem with json or even server response. As i can see your update, the problem is same as mine, IE dont allow a submit at all, so no request = no response.

Im trying to figure out whats the problem, example on the author page works - mine not.

Comment: No, IE submits the form, because it saves me my image :). I've solved my problem by setting `$this->auto_render = false` (Kohana framework) when is also `internal` ($this->request->is_internal()) request and now it works correctly :).

Comment: sorry then, i have similar problem - cant event start file upload because of "access denied" on submit();