# Malsup jQuery Form Plugin upload in IE redirect 302

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-forms-plugin

In every other browser the multi upload form works. Only IE doesn't like it. When i try to submit the form IE starts a 302 redirect on the page in the action="" attribute. The redirect is going to the root of my site.

I already tried it with the iframe/textarea but this also doesn't work. I test it on IE7, IE8, IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Here](https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/302) .

This problem has been discussed on github.

Then it helps to understand exactly what the plugin is doing. Since IE < 10 does not support ajax file uploads, the plugin simulates the user experience by submitting the original form with the response targeted to a dynamically created iframe. When the iframe loads the server response, the plugin extracts the response and invokes callback handlers.

In the case where the server responds with a header content-type set to "application/json" that trigger's IE's default download behavior. To avoid this, do not set the content-type header to "application/json". Leave it as text/html or text/plain.

> In the case where the server has an actual error it will return an
>   error response page with appropriate status codes set in the response
>   header. This presents two problems for the plugin:

1. It cannot access the response headers
2. It cannot determine from the response body whether or not the
   request was successful

> A potential solution, if you have control over the error response
>   page, is to add attributes on the body element that the plugin will
>   look for. The plugin will attempt to access "status" and "statusText"
>   attributes on the response's body element. So if your error page
>   includes something like  then your error handler
>   will be triggered.

**It's just need do little hack for the IE**

1. use text/html or text/plain instead of 'application/json'.
2. fully control for the error response, add error message in the successful response body, and then extract and handle it.

[No JSON response in jQuery form plugin in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881267/no-json-response-in-jquery-form-plugin-in-ie9)